# strange thread deadlock with SDL 1.2 on raspberry pi

Tags: c, multithreading, sdl

I have been working with a simple bi-threaded application with two threads running simultaneously. Each thread plots a figure(a triangle/ a rectangle) to a predefined and mutually exclusive section of the screen. That is, both threads, never write in each other's screen space.

After running the program for a long time, say 5hours or so, the main thread keeps running , but the other thread freezes(it doesn't die though).

I get this in backtrace o/p, which shows a deadlock I guess.

```
Thread 2 (Thread 0xb542f440 (LWP 2142)):
#0  0xb6e83258 in __lll_lock_wait ()
   from /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libpthread.so.0
#1  0xb6e7de38 in pthread_mutex_lock ()
   from /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libpthread.so.0
#2  0xb6ef8de4 in SDL_mutexP ()
   from /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libSDL-1.2.so.0
#3  0xb6ef4058 in ?? () from /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libSDL-1.2.so.0
#4  0xb6ef4058 in ?? () from /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libSDL-1.2.so.0
Backtrace stopped: previous frame identical to this frame (corrupt stack?)
```

Is it really a libSDL1.2 issue? Do I have to write explicit user defined mutex for every SDL_Blit/or other operations with SDL, that I am doing? Or is it something else that I am missing? How would I solve this issue?

I am using:
libSDL1.2 available in Raspberry Pi
libPthreads
libSDL_ttf

EDIT: gdb trace of the thread 2 mutex:

(gdb) p *(pthread_mutex_t*) 0xb542ed38
$3 = {_*data = {*_lock = 39257160, __count = 1048617, __owner = 0,
    __kind = 7078021, _*nusers = 0, {*_spins = 0, _*list = {*_next = 0x0}}},
  __size = "H\004W\002)\000\020\000\000\000\000\000\205\000l\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000", __align = 39257160}

Let me know if you need more information.

Answer (score 1):

This approach will only work with software surfaces (w/o hardware acceleration). With hardware surfaces it, at best, would lock and wait - which have no performance benefits anyway; and in bad case (judging by quick look at SDL source) it could end badly, by the simple logic how SDL_LockSurface works.

I'm not even sure your external mutexes would help, since hardware accelerated graphics access should almost always be locked to one thread (OpenGL is good example - each thread have it's own separate drawing context).

In short, i see no reason why you should use two threads for drawing, but in any case it isn't guaranteed to be thread-safe.

Comment: yes, I am blitting directly onto the SDL HW surface. But, I don't understand, how could it freeze after 3,29,00,000 calls? Please see my updated question.

Comment: I don't see any updates in question, only formatting edits. Anyway, it's just a coincidence. You relied upon something that you really shouldn't, - so results are unpredictable - as you've already noticed.

Comment: so should I keep killing and respawning the thread every 1million times? or Should I abandon SDL and move to openGL?

Comment: OpenGL doesn't allow multi threading on the same context either, see e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11097170/multithreaded-rendering-on-opengl

Comment: @askmish you shouldn't render into HW surface from two threads. That's all. Problem could happen at any single call, not 'once in a while'. GL wouldn't help you too.

Comment: What is the straight fix of this problem? Moving all drawing onto HW surface in one, single main thread and offloading only I/O events into the other?

Comment: @askmish why do you want multithreading? Isn't Pi have only one CPU core?

Comment: @askmish Yes. Though the RPI has just 1 CPU/core, so multi threading something here will only help if you're doing blocking calls, otherwise it'll just slow you down more.

Comment: @keltar: yes, I am drawing the figures based on touch responses. so, I don't want my main to be blocked by touchscreen IO.

Comment: @askmish well that's a question why your IO is blocking. If you can't make it non-blocking, go ahead with separate thread. Isn't some form of event polling an option here?

Comment: @askmish touchscreen wouldn't be considered as blocking or as I/O in the normal cases, a mouse and keyboard isn't either, unless you have to use some blocking library to perform this.