# MFC: how to draw opengl from a different thread?

Tags: multithreading, opengl, mfc

I am trying to do some opengl 1.0 animation in a CWnd window with 60 fps. I create a sub class of CWnd:

class COpenGLControl : public CWnd
{
...
}

I found if I use the build-in timer "setTimer()" and set it to fire on every 1000/60 ms, all the opengl commands were able to render correctly. However, If I implement my own timer using a separate thread, nothing is drawn. All I got was a black screen.

Is there a way to issue opengl commands from a different thread?

Comment: Please read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11097170/multithreaded-rendering-on-opengl

Comment: Thanks for the reply. After reading the post, it seems what I am doing is kinda different. I am not trying to multi-thread my renderer. I just want to do all my opengl calls in a single thread other than the CWnd thread, and cross-platform. That's why I am doing my own timer

Comment: Perhaps error code may help a bit to investigate. A context must be bound in the thread from which you are calling commands.

Comment: How can I get the error code? I created the context in the OnCreate() function, and GL calls are made from my timer thread. Maybe this is the problem. Would work If I create the context also in the timer thread?

Comment: GetLastError will give the error code. @derhass gave you a proper answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if you are not intending to issue GL calls from multiple threads, you have to take OpenGL's rules for threading into account: An OpenGL context can only be used by at most one thread at a time. (And, per thread, there can be at most one active GL context at any time). That does not mean that you cannot use the same context in multiple threads, or create it in one and use it in another, you just have to explicitely "hand over" the context from one thread to another.

I don't know if you use some further librariy for GL context handling, so I'm assuming you are using the native API of your OS - in this case wgl. The relevant function is [`wglMakeCurrent()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd374387%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). So, to hand over a context which is "current" in thread A to thread B, thread A must first call `wglMakeCurrent(NULL,NULL)` before thread B can get the context via `wglMakeCurrent(someDC, myGLCtx)`. You can of course switch around a GL context as many times you like, but that will introduce a huge synchronization overhead and should be avoided.

From your comments:

> Would work If I create the context also in the timer thread?

Yes, it would.

Just a side note: *Creating* is not the issue here at all, since creating a GL context does not automatically make it "current" to a thread - so you can just create it in thread A and afterwards make it current directly to thread B.

Comment: Thanks so much. This solves my problem. As for the performance, all of the drawing will be done on the timer thread. Only some initial setup will be done on the UI thread, which will be before the timer is fired. So I believe this should be ok.