# Is SDL_UpdateTexture threadsafe?

Tags: c++, linux, sdl

I have a program that deals with a texture sized 1920x1080 and updates the texture via `SDL_UpdateTexture` in a multithreaded environment. The Texture is "tiled" between the threads, so thread 1 will update a different area than thread 2. For example `t1` will update the area `0,0,64,64` and `t2` will update `65, 65, 128, 128`.

Can `SDL_UpdateTexture` be used in this case without any locking, so that the threads can update the texture conucurrently?

Comment: You already have an answer, but if you want to update texture frequently - you need a streaming texture, not static one (and UpdateTexture is for static textures), and with streaming textures you can use LockTexture, then update parts in different threads, and UnlockTexture in graphics thread.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, streaming MIGHT be faster. In my case (I did benchmarks) the UpdateTexture function is faster (2ms vs 10ms). But thanks anyway for that hint!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at

[Multithreaded Rendering on OpenGL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11097170/multithreaded-rendering-on-opengl)

But, briefly: GL isn't thread-safe (or even thread-aware). On Windows, you can't have the context active on more than one thread at a time, so you wouldn't be able to update your texture without synchronizing the threads (which defeats the purpose of multithreading). I'd wager that it's the same on Linux.

Comment: Thank you very much. I think that SDL might handle that inside of the lib somehow. But then I will just create another thread that is in charge of uploading the texture and the threads to update the pixel data. Thank you.

Comment: @Nidhoegger If you're feeling adventurous, have a look at Vulkan. It's not for the feint of heart, but command buffers, etc. make it a lot easier to implement a performant multi-threaded renderer. Also, with SDL: https://developer.tizen.org/development/guides/native-application/graphics/simple-directmedia-layer-sdl/sdl-graphics-vulkan%C2%AE

Comment: I was planning to have a look at vulkan at some point. Maybe that point is now reached :P. Thanks for that tip!